# How can I extend spinner to implement a new function?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to extend `Spinner` Android class in my code to implement a new function, but for some reason this didn't work.

This is the extended class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {

    public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setSelectionByItemId(AdapterView<?> parent, long id){
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount(); i++) {              
            long itemIdAtPosition = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
            if (itemIdAtPosition == id) {
                parent.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the way I'm instantiating this class:

```
CustomSpinner spinner = (CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.sphofentries);
```

This give me an error at runtime.

All this is if `R.id.sphofentries` is declared in my layout as an spinner.

But now, if I declare `sphofentries` as a `CustomSpinner` I get a runtime error just in the moment I set the Layout to the Activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Also I am pretty sure that the problem is that I need to declare `sphofentries` as a `CustomSpinner` because if I do this:

```
CustomSpinner spinner = new CustomSpinner(this);
spinner = (CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.sphofentries);
```

This goes without problem trough the first line but gives a runtime error in the second then the problem isn't creating a new `CustomSpinner` but setting the `sphofentries` in this `CustomSpinner` (This with `sphofentries` declared like a `Spinner` not a `CustomSpinner`).

Maybe I am doing something wrong in the layout, this is the way I am declaring `sphofentries` as a `CustomSpinner`:

```
<CustomSpinner 
    android:id="@+id/sphofentries"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvhofentries"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

Comment: CustomSpinner spinner = new CustomSpinner(this);
spinner = (CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.sphofentries);
means that you don't understand how android works. Before trying to write your own widgets, I'd recommend to read and test the basic examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally there was two reasons for this to not work properly, the two previous answers are right:

1. It's necessary to define also the second constructor with the AttributeSet parameter.

   ```
   public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   ```
2. In the layout the Spinner must be defined as a CustomSpinner and needs to be declared with all the fully qualified name:

   ```
   <net.domain.package.CustomSpinner  
       android:id="@+id/sphofentries" 
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvhofentries"
       android:layout_width="300dip"       
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   />
   ```

Comment: @fishjd okay, made the change.

Comment: is there a way to avoid using fully qualified name? declare, import something, somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

It's a common mistake. Just add this constructor, which is the one called by the layout inflater:

```
public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the debugger do not even get to enter this function (not the other).

I edited the question to the test I've done.

Answer (score 2):

Is sphofentries a `Spinner` or a `CustomSpinner`?

It would need to be declared as a `CustomSpinner` in your layout for you to cast it as a `CustomSpinner` in your code.

The other way around would work.  You would be able to cast a `CustomSpinner` as a `Spinner`, because it is a subclass.

Comment: I edited the question considering your answer. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the layout?

Comment: I've done the very same thing before in my layouts and it works, the only difference is I had to use the fully qualified namespace (or package or whatever it is called in java).  Try using the fully qualified name in your layout and see if that makes a difference.  (i.e. <com.example.CustomSpinner />